# Parsing NSDate from string

Tags: string, nsdate

Method dateFromString always return time greater than one hour. Examples:

*String "2013-08-31 **00**:00:00" -> NSDate "2013-08-31 **01**:00:00 MSK"*

*String "2013-08-31 **11**:59:59" -> NSDate "2013-08-31 **12**:59:59 MSK"*

I try this:

```
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]]; and 
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
```

the result is the same...

And this:

```
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
```

*String "2013-08-31 **00**:00:00" -> NSDate "2013-08-31 **05**:00:00 MSK"   (+4 hour)*

**I need get same time that there is in string:**

*String "2013-08-31 00:00:00" -> NSDate "2013-08-31 00:00:00 MSK"*

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use followingon it is working fine for me :

```
+(NSString *)getDateInStringFormat:(NSDate *)creationDate {

    NSDateFormatter *createDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [createDateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
    [createDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *currentDateString = [createDateFormatter stringFromDate:creationDate];
    //NSLog(@"Prfile creation date is = %@",ProfileCreationDate);
    return currentDateString;
}
```

Comment: I need get NSDate from String, not String from NSDate. I also try:
    [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
 - it did not help :(